# Visual Studio 2012 Route Template not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, routes

Working on a SPA tutorial by John Papas that accesses a SQL Server Compact DB. When I use the URL to access the list of Speakers in the App, it throws a 404 error. I have tried to troubleshoot this the past hour by going over the tutorial videos again but I am not having any luck.

The tutorial has me accessing via the following URL: localhost:xxxxx/api/speakers.

Thus, my URL looks something like this: localhost:12345/api/speakers

```
 Error message: {"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49357/api/speakers'.","messageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'speakers'."}
```

The speakers.html is located in the App folder.

Here is my WebApiConfig.cs under App_Start:

```
 using System.Web.Http;
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

 namespace CodeCamper
 {
     public static class WebApiConfig
 {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Configure(config);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    private static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}}
```

This is the SpeakersController provided by the tutorial:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CodeCamper.Controllers
{
    public class SpeakersController
    {
    // GET api/speakers
    public IEnumerable<object> Get()
    {
        var ctx = new CodeCamperDbContext();
        var query = ctx.Set<Session>()
            .Select(session => session.Speaker)
            .Distinct().Select(s =>
                new
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        FirstName = s.FirstName,
                        LastName = s.LastName,
                        ImageSource = s.ImageSource,
                    });
        return query;
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit `SpeakersController` from `ApiController`

```
public class SpeakersController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
   //your code
}
```

and add

add `HttpRoute("api/speakers")` just before your controller definition after `// GET api/speakers`

Comment: Sanjay Nishad, adding `HttpRoute("api/speakers")` is not required. As you can see in the code sample from the quesion @HermesTrismegistus defines route template.

Comment: @feeeper You are right, but I faced this issue some time, because it written code and not scaffolding

Comment: Such a rookie mistake! I guess sometimes it doesn't pay to code when tired. I can't believe I forgot to extend the controller from the API controller. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit your `SpeakersController` from the `ApiController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CodeCamper.Controllers
{
  public class SpeakersController: System.Web.Http.ApiController // <-- here it is
  {
    // GET api/speakers
    public IEnumerable<object> Get()
    {
      var ctx = new CodeCamperDbContext();
      var query = ctx.Set<Session>()
          .Select(session => session.Speaker)
          .Distinct().Select(s =>
              new
                  {
                      Id = s.Id,
                      FirstName = s.FirstName,
                      LastName = s.LastName,
                      ImageSource = s.ImageSource,
                  });
      return query;
    }
  }
}
```